# WCF: Cant get my Web service to work, on the server

Tags: c#, wcf, service, config

My issue is that i have this Webservice `EService` that works really great in my debug projekt, but when i implement it into a WinForm projekt, and put the service on a server. I get this error when crateing the client?

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' 
occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll

Could not find default endpoint element that references contract '{0}' in the ServiceModel
client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application,
or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
```

App.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEService" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://Domane.dk/EService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IEService" contract="IEService"
      name="BasicHttpBinding_IEService" />
</client>
```

Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

The way im calling it

```
using (var test = new EServiceAPI.EServiceClient())
        {
            test.OpdaterLeastDatoWinPLC(connstr);
        }
```

I cant se the reason why it fails. Sorry for being such a newbi. And yes i've harvestet the internet for 2 days trying to find a solusion now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem when using a web service in a dll.
Try this:

```
    using (var test = CreateWebServiceInstance("http://url.to.mywebservice.com"))
    {
        test.OpdaterLeastDatoWinPLC(connstr);
    }
```

Enter the correct url to the web service above and create the client using the code below. You still need to add the web service to the project so that the class EServiceClient is created for you.

```
    internal static EServiceAPI.EServiceClient CreateWebServiceInstance(string url) {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        binding.AllowCookies = false;
        binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
        binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
        binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
        binding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
        binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 5242880;
        return new EServiceAPI.EServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(url));
    }
```

If it works you can modify the settings above to suit your needs better.

Comment: I dont know how or why, but this works. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with the `<endpoint address="http://Domane.dk/EService.svc"` i believe it should be a relative path when using on a server.

Like:
`<endpoint address="./EService.svc"`